# Can't refresh snap-store

Tags: snap

i've started to use Ubuntu last month.
I'm getting this error in the terminal while i'm trying to refresh snap-store

```
$ sudo snap refresh snap-store 
error: cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps
       (ubuntu-software)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: why do you need to refresh snap store ? It'll be automatically refreshed

Comment: `sudo snap refresh` try this instead

Comment: *snap* packages that are open or running, cannot be refreshed.  You need to close the running *snap* package before you can update/refresh it  (ie. close `ubuntu-software`)

Comment: @ConMan77 no, it is not. When I open software center it itself shows a message that snap-store cannot be upgraded because of running processes. I would not notice this problem otherwise.

Comment: @guiverc When I run "snap refresh" no process named "ubuntu-software" is running.

Comment: @guiverc The message is INCORRECT.  Snap pretends the program in parentheses is running.  Closing ubuntu-software is not possible because it is not running.  The pids it names belong to processes dbus-launch and /usr/bin/dbus-daemon.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Working for me:

```
ps -e | grep snap-store #id blocking process
kill #id
sudo snap refresh
```

Comment: Worked for me too! Ty <3

Comment: Or `sudo killall snap-store`

Comment: Or `sudo pkill snap-store`

Answer (score 22):

I had the same error.

First: `sudo killall snap-store`

Then: `sudo snap refresh snap-store`

After this, open your snap store (or "Ubuntu Software") again and you will see it's updated.

Comment: Wait few minutes for `Handling re-refresh of "snap-store" as needed`.

Comment: So depressing we still have to crack open the terminal to manage basic update functionality in 2024...

Answer (score 2):

```
killall snap-store
snap refresh
```

Note: You don't need to type these comments with sudo. In fact it is encouraged not to use sudo here

Answer (score 0):

Snaps will be automatically updated according to the
[documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started#heading--refreshing).